# Calculating vertex position after rotating in 3D space

Tags: javascript, math, 3d, rotation, trigonometry

I am trying to rotate on Y axis in javascript ( In my own 3D engine )
and i tried this function :

```
function rotateY(amount) {
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    points[i].z = Math.sin(amount) * points[i].x + Math.cos(amount) * points[i].z;
    points[i].x = Math.cos(amount) * points[i].x - Math.sin(amount) * points[i].z;
  }
}
```

It is rotating, but every time it rotates it changes it's x and z scale so it is getting thinner.. Can you help me how to rotate it properly ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming i) the rotation is respective to the global origin and not the object itself and ii) that you want to apply a delta (if we can't take these, see below):

For each point:
1. Find the distance of the point relative to the axis.
2. Find the current angle of the point relative to the axis.
3. Use basic 2-D cos/sin [polar projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates), since the excluded axis is a [unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector).

```
function rotateY( points, deltaAngle ) {

    const _points = points;

    if ( ! Array.isArray( points ) ) points = [ points ];

    for ( let i = 0; i < points.length; i ++ ) {

        const newAngle = Math.atan2( points[ i ].z, points[ i ].x ) + deltaAngle;
        const distance = ( points[ i ].x ** 2 + points[ i ].z ** 2 ) ** ( 1 / 2 );

        points[ i ].x = distance * Math.cos( newAngle );
        points[ i ].z = distance * Math.sin( newAngle );

    }

    return _points;

}
```

The algorithm is the same for X and Z rotation, so long as the first axis used in `Math.atan2` is the same axis that uses `Math.sin`.

> NOTE: I used the [exponentiation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation_(**)). I wouldn't use this in production unless you're using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)/something similar or don't care about IE/old users.

---

If assumption ii) cannot be taken, we simply want to store the original angles of the points and have `newAngle` defined as the original angle plus the new angle.

If assumption i) cannot be taken, it gets complicated. If the object's axes are simply offset, you can subtract that offset in `newAngle` and `distance` and add it back when setting `x` and `z`. If the axes themselves are not respectively parallel to the global axes, you'll want to switch to using a [quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) to avoid [gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock). I would suggest copying or at least looking [three.js's implementation](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/math/Quaternion.js).

Comment: But one more question, what do you mean as const distance? Distance between what?

Comment: From the y-axis. Say you have point { x: 1, y: 6, z: 0 }, the distance is from the y-axis would be 1. Since the axes are unit vectors you could imagine the 3-D global space and a single slice of that space, defined as y = 6, as the plane { x: 1, y: 6, z: 0} lies on. On this plane, { x: 1, z: 0 } is 1 unit away from the origin. [Here's a figure.](https://i.imgur.com/t6ATK04.png)

Comment: Any suggestion for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68677748/calculate-mat4-rotate-on-vertex-position